# Should I share session across tab when user uncheck Remember me

Tags: login, remember-me

Currently, my website always remembers login i.e. there's no Remember me checkbox. I was requested to implement the checkbox.

I have 2 options about the behavior when the user **open a new tab** of the website **after** they login **without** Remember me:

- Share the session between tab: All tabs share the logged in session. The session will be cleared when the user closes browser window, but not a single tab.
- New login for each tab: This means the user can open 10 tab, each has its own session e.g. different user.

What is the generally accepted way of doing this now? And what was the way years ago, when technologies like local/session storage & BroadcastChannel wasn't available yet?

Answer (score 1):

**For most cases, share the session across tabs.** Users often engage with multiple concurrent tabs to complete workflows, like comparing different records, or investigating another page without leaving what they were doing before. Forcing another sign-in is a hassle for the user.

There is an exception to this, and that is when your product doesn't support concurrent tabs. If things break or fall apart when a second tab is open, don't let the user log in. Simply let them know that they are already logged in.